# How does the modulus operator work?

Tags: c++, modulus

Let's say that I need to format the output of an array to display a fixed number of elements per line. How do I go about doing that using modulus operation?

Using C++, the code below works for displaying 6 elements per line but I have no idea how and why it works?

```
for ( count = 0 ; count < size ; count++)
{
    cout << somearray[count];
    if( count % 6 == 5) cout << endl;
}
```

What if I want to display 5 elements per line? How do i find the exact expression needed?

Comment: Please note that the name of the operation is **modulo operation**. The term **modulus** is the role given to `b` in `a % b`.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 44):

in C++ expression `a % b` returns remainder of division of a by b (if they are positive. For negative numbers sign of result is implementation defined). For example:

```
5 % 2 = 1
13 % 5 = 3
```

With this knowledge we can try to understand your code. Condition `count % 6 == 5` means that newline will be written when remainder of division count by 6 is five. How often does that happen? Exactly 6 lines apart (excercise : write numbers 1..30 and underline the ones that satisfy this condition), starting at 6-th line (count = 5).

To get desired behaviour from your code, you should change condition to `count % 5 == 4`, what will give you newline every 5 lines, starting at 5-th line (count = 4).

Comment: "For negative numbers sign of result is implementation defined" This isn't true in C++11 - see ISO14882:2011(e) 5.6-4 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508.

Comment: what operands does modulo expects? Why doesn;t it work with float values?

Answer (score 8):

Basically modulus Operator gives you remainder 
simple Example in maths what's left over/remainder of 11 divided by 3? answer is 2

for same thing C++ has  **modulus operator ('%')**

Basic code for explanation

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int num = 11;
    cout << "remainder is " << (num % 3) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Which will display

> remainder is 2

Answer (score 4):

This JSFiddle project could help you to understand how modulus work:
http://jsfiddle.net/elazar170/7hhnagrj

The modulus function works something like this:

```
     function modulus(x,y){
       var m = Math.floor(x / y);
       var r = m * y;
       return x - r;
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

It gives you the remainder of a division.

```
int c=11, d=5;
cout << (c/d) * d + c % d; // gives you the value of c
```

Answer (score 2):

You can think of the modulus operator as giving you a remainder. count % 6 divides 6 out of count as many times as it can and gives you a remainder from 0 to 5 (These are all the possible remainders because you already divided out 6 as many times as you can). The elements of the array are all printed in the for loop, but every time the remainder is 5 (every 6th element), it outputs a newline character. This gives you 6 elements per line. For 5 elements per line, use

> if (count % 5 == 4)