# using % on a double in c++

Tags: c++, operators, double

im trying to use the % operator on a double in c++, i have done the same in java and it works fine.

is there something im missing here or is this not allowed, sorry im new to c++ so might be making a really stupid error here

```
    double i =  full_price_in_pence / 100.0;
    double j = full_price_in_pence % 100;
    int final_pounds = (int) i;
    int final_pence = (int) j;
```

and these are both double values

```
full_price_in_pence
full_price_in_pounds
```

Comment: You _don't want_ to use a double to represent money.  At least,  not in a real application.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138790/cant-use-modulus-on-doubles

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `std::fmod()` function from the `<cmath>` Standard header:

```
#include <cmath>

// ...

double j = fmod(full_price_in_pence, 100);
```

Answer (score 3):

`%` is for integers only, you're looking for `fmod`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use % operator for a double variable. Only int variables are allowed to do that.

You can check some good answers from another question like this; you can find them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556946/how-does-the-modulus-operator-work).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not allowed. Operands of the `%` operator must be of integral types. Use `std::fmod()` instead.