# C++ expected primary-expression before ';' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I get an error message that states "expected primary-expression ';' token" and it highlights my percentage formula. I have tried to rearrange my code, but it seems the problem is not in it.

```
const int TOTALSUITES = 120;

for (int floor = 10; floor <= 16; floor++) {
    if ( floor != 13) {
        do { 
            cout << "Please enter the number of suites occupied on the floor " << floor << ":";
            cin >> numOccupied; 

            if ((numOccupied <0) || (numOccupied >20 )) {  
                goodChoice = false;
                cout << "\n\t\t**ERROR" << numOccupied << " ***\n\n";
                cout << "*** Choice must be from [0-20]***\n";
            }
            else {
                goodChoice = true;
            }
            totalOccupied += numOccupied; 
        } while (!goodChoice);
    }
 }

percentage = (totalOccupied / TOTALSUITES) * 100% ;
cout << endl;
cout << "Hotel has " << TOTALSUITES << endl;
cout << "Number of occupied suites is " << totalOccupied << endl;
cout << "The percentage of occupied suites is " << percentage << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: in which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 4):

% used here is the modulo operator which is a binary operator...
so this is what you have to do...

```
percentage = (totalOccupied / TOTALSUITES)* 100;
```

//and then where you have cout percentage at that point...do this

```
cout<<"the percentage of occupied suites is"<<percentage<<"%";
```

Comment: "%" symbol i have used in cout statement is just to display the percentage sign and has no logical effect on code

Comment: @SunnySmile24 if my answer or any else answer u found appropriate then mark as most appropriate i.e. the tick below the upvote and downvote buttons...so that other people knew that its answer has been already answered

Answer (score 1):

`100%` is not 100 percent.  `100%` is trying to use the [`%` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556946/how-does-the-modulus-operator-work) in an incorrect manner.  To multiply by 100% you just use `1` which is not needed as anything times 1 is itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
percentage = (totalOccupied / TOTALSUITES) * 100% ;
```

This is not valid syntax. Change it to this.

```
percentage = (totalOccupied / TOTALSUITES);
```

Assuming your `totalOccupied` is not a float, you should probably do this as well:

```
percentage = (static_cast<float>(totalOccupied) / TOTALSUITES);
```

Comment: I have been struggling on it for a while T.T Thank you a lot <3 !!

Comment: I'd prefer to see a `double` (and would upvote), but I get your point.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is actually the *modulus* operator in C++, requiring two arguments.

`100%` is therefore not syntactically valid.

Assuming that you want `%` to stand-in for a "divide by 100" operator, the simplest thing to do in your case is to drop the `100%` from your code.

Note that `totalOccupied / TOTALSUITES` will be carried out in *integer arithmetic* if `totalOccupied` is also an `int` or `unsigned`. Fix that by promoting one of the arguments to a `double`, or pre-multiply the term with `1.0`.