# Arithmetic Exception in gdb, but I'm not dividing by zero?

Tags: c++, exception, gdb, arithmeticexception

I've been getting a `Floating point exception (core dumped)` error in my C++ program, and gdb shows that the problem is on a line that performs modulo division:

```
Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff6804700 (LWP 13931)]
0x00000000004023e8 in CompExp::eval (this=0x7fffec000e40, currVal=0)
    at exp.cpp:55
55              return (r==0) ? 0 : l % r;
```

The line guards against dividing by zero, and my backtrace shows the following:

```
#0  0x00000000004023e8 in CompExp::eval (this=0x7fffec000e40, currVal=0)
    at exp.cpp:55
        l = -2147483648
        r = -1
```

Since I know I'm not dividing by zero, what else could possibly be causing the exception?

Comment: The modulo of a negative number is undefined, it's probably that, you probably should have (r <= 0)

Comment: @PeterJ, Interesting, the operation, in my opinion, makes sense for a negative number, but you're right.

Answer (score 11):

So I figured out what was causing the problem -- An arithmetic exception can be triggered either by dividing by zero, or overflow of a *signed* integer, which is what happened here. Unsigned integers are required to wrap around when overflowed; the behavior for signed integers is undefined.

Answer (score 6):

Change the code to the following to avoid trying to take the modulo of a negative number which is undefined:

```
return (r<=0) ? 0 : l % r;
```

Comment: This seems to have changed in C++11. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values).

Comment: If I make a small program with only `int i = -2147483648 % -1;`, then there is no exception, so I don't think that it would be a problem with taking the modulo of a negative number.

Comment: @chris, interesting, I suspect it's one of those edge cases that some compilers handle differently.

Comment: @PeterJ, Well, before C++11, it was implementation-defined, so they're free to do what they will. It is interesting that the standard revisited that, though.

Comment: @crognale The compiler is [folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) that constant expression, so that `i` gets assigned to the expression result during compilation, not at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate such modulo expression: `-2147483648 % -1`, a division is required, which in this case, seems to be a 32-bit division (I guess `l` and `r` are defined as `int`). The right result of such division would be `2147483648`, but that value cannot be represented in 32-bit, so an arithmetic exception is produced.