# Clang giving very different performance for expressions which intuitively should be equivalent

Tags: c++, performance, clang, performance-testing, clang++

Could someone explain me these considerable performance differences between these expressions which I would expect to give similar performance. I'm compiling with Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) in release mode.

Here's my test code (just change CASE to 1, 2, 3 or 4 to test yourself):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

#define CASE 1

inline int foo(int n) {
    return
#if CASE == 1
    (n % 2) ? 9 : 6

#elif CASE == 2
    (n % 2) == true ? 9 : 6

#elif CASE == 3
    6 + (n % 2) * 3

#elif CASE == 4
    6 + bool(n % 2) * 3

#endif
    ;
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    int n = argc;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
        n += foo(n);
    }

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;

    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "\n";
    std::cout << "value: " << n << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

And here are the timings I get:

```
CASE   EXPRESSION                TIME
1      (n % 2) ? 9 : 6           0.1585
2      (n % 2) == true ? 9 : 6   0.3491
3      6 + (n % 2) * 3           0.2559
4      6 + bool(n % 2) * 3       0.1906
```

Here's the difference in assembly between CASE 1 and CASE 2:

CASE 1:

```
Ltmp12:
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- RSI
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: i <- 0
    .loc    1 24 0                  ## /Test/main.cpp:24:0
    movl    %ebx, %ecx
    andl    $1, %ecx
    leal    (%rcx,%rcx,2), %ecx
Ltmp13:
    .loc    1 48 14                 ## /Test/main.cpp:48:14
    leal    6(%rbx,%rcx), %ebx
```

CASE 2:

```
Ltmp12:
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- RSI
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: i <- 0
    .loc    1 24 0                  ## /Test/main.cpp:24:0
    movl    %ebx, %ecx
    shrl    $31, %ecx
    addl    %ebx, %ecx
    andl    $-2, %ecx
    movl    %ebx, %edx
    subl    %ecx, %edx
    cmpl    $1, %edx
    sete    %cl
    movzbl  %cl, %ecx
    leal    (%rcx,%rcx,2), %ecx
Ltmp13:
    .loc    1 48 14                 ## /Test/main.cpp:48:14
    leal    6(%rbx,%rcx), %ebx
```

And here's the difference in assembly between CASE 3 and CASE 4:

CASE 3:

```
Ltmp12:
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- RSI
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: i <- 0
    .loc    1 24 0                  ## /Test/main.cpp:24:0
    movl    %ebx, %ecx
    shrl    $31, %ecx
    addl    %ebx, %ecx
    andl    $-2, %ecx
    movl    %ebx, %edx
    subl    %ecx, %edx
    leal    (%rdx,%rdx,2), %ecx
Ltmp13:
    .loc    1 48 14                 ## /Test/main.cpp:48:14
    leal    6(%rbx,%rcx), %ebx
```

CASE 4:

```
Ltmp12:
LBB0_1:                                 ## =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: main:argv <- RSI
    ##DEBUG_VALUE: i <- 0
    .loc    1 24 0                  ## /Test/main.cpp:24:0
    movl    %ebx, %ecx
    andl    $1, %ecx
    negl    %ecx
    andl    $3, %ecx
Ltmp13:
    .loc    1 48 14                 ## /Test/main.cpp:48:14
    leal    6(%rbx,%rcx), %ebx
```

Comment: And your compilation flags are?? It's an absolutely pointless comparison without knowing which optimizations were applied. So far - different number of assembly instructions give different execution time, that much should be obvious.

Comment: I'm using Xcode, so I don't easily see all the flags, but one important flag I can see is -Os

Comment: What does `-O2` look like? Otherwise, it looks like optimizer fail.

Comment: For both, clang++ and g++ at coliru (`-O3`), `(n % 2) != false ? 9 : 6` is significantly faster than `(n % 2) == true ? 9 : 6`

Comment: @dyp That's very interesting! Looks like an optimizer corner case.

Comment: @Berkus `bool(n % 2) != false ? 9 : 6` is as fast as both `bool(n % 2) == true ? 9 : 6` and `(n % 2) ? 9 : 6`

Comment: But you just said it's significantly faster?

Comment: @dyp: I shared it (with O2) for easier review [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e166cc6d2b1ff33) They all get the same IR (`%1 = and i32 %n, 1` + `%2 = icmp ne i32 %1, 0`) except `(n % 2) == true ? 9 : 6` which gets `%1 = srem i32 %n, 2` + `%2 = icmp eq i32 %1, 1` for some reason.

Comment: @berkus Those snippets are different. `bool(n % 2) == true ? 9 : 6` contains an explicit conversion to `bool`, whereas `(n % 2) == true ? 9 : 6` does not. The first one is significantly faster than the second.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Hmm.. Note this problem is not clang-specific, coliru's g++4.8.2 behaves similarly.

Comment: @dyp: Yes, I am just better at reading LLVM IR so I prefer Clang here; I cannot understand the issue though :/

Comment: @dyp So in second case it's actually doing an integer compare to true?

Comment: @berkus See my anwer :)

Comment: I'm curious: what is the time (and the assembly) you obtain for `6+(n&1)+((n&1)<<1)`? and for `3*(2+(n&1))`? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer currently only covers the difference between the first two cases.

---

What are the possible values of `(n % 2)`? Surely, it's `0` and `1`, right?

Wrong. It's `0`, `1` **and** `-1`. Because `n` is a *signed integer*, and [the result of `%` can be negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values).

`(n % 2) ? 6 : 9` implicitly converts the expression `n % 2` to `bool`. The result of this conversion is `true` IFF the value **nonzero**. The conversion therefore is equivalent to `(n % 2) != 0`.

In, `(n % 2) == true ? 6 : 9`, for the comparison `(n % 2) == true`, the *usual arithmetic conversions* are applied to both sides (note that `bool` is an arithmetic type). `true` is promoted to an `int` of value `1`. So the conversion is equivalent to `(n % 2) == 1`.

The two conversions `(n % 2) != 0` and `(n % 2) == 1` *yield different results for a negative `n`*: Let `n = -1`. Then `n % 2 == -1`, and `-1 != 0` is `true`, but `-1 == 1` is `false`.

Therefore, the compiler has to introduce some additional complexity to cope with the sign.

The difference in runtime disappears if you make `n` an *unsigned integer*, or remove the sign issue any other way (e.g. by comparing `n % 2 != false`).

---

I got this idea by looking at the assembly output, especially the following line:

```
shrl    $31, %eax
```

Using the highest bit made no sense to me first, until I realized the highest bit is used as the sign.

Comment: There's also no difference between cases 3 and 4 when using an `unsigned int`. Both are slower than cases 1 and 2, though.