# C++ modulus operator circular array

Tags: c++, modulus

I am trying to achieve a "wrap around" effect in a circular array. When I push an item to front, I want it to be stored in decreasing locations. When I push to front, I'm trying something like this:

```
items[front] = ch;
front = (front - 1) % capacity;
```

But this does not wrap around like I would expect. Front starts out at 0, and when the second line executes, front becomes -1. Shouldn't front become 6 after the second line executes? My data structures textbook seems to think so.

Comment: Could you give us more code for context? What data type is `front`? What is the value of `capacity`?

Comment: If `front` isn't an `unsigned` type, then this behavior is perfectly normal.

Comment: Especially pre-C++11, take note of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values

Comment: Front is an int. I guess I just didn't realize that is how modulus works...

Answer (score 3):

That is how `%` works in c++. To get the effect you want try this:

```
front = (front + capacity - 1) % capacity;
```

Comment: `front = (front > 0 ? front : capacity) - 1;` sounds better to me. Also, if `front` is an `unsigned` type then OP's operation should be correct too.