# Why is my function not working properly

Tags: c++, function

My function that checks if numbers in the vector are even or odd doesn't work properly.
This function prints the numbers that i have typed in the vector and puts them in 2 categories EVENS/ODDS. But if i have a negative number there is a problem with the odds not printing it but evens work.
problematic code is here:

```
void printEvensAndOddsVector(const vector <int>& new_v1)
{
    cout << "Vector Evens: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < new_v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (new_v1.at(i) % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << new_v1.at(i) << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << " \n";

    cout << "Vector Odds: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < new_v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (new_v1.at(i) % 2 == 1) // Here is the problem.
        {
            cout << new_v1.at(i) << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << " \n";
}
```

Or more exactly this line: `if (new_v1.at(i) % 2 == 1)`
It prints the numbers that are odd but only the positive ones not the negative ones.
But if i change it to `if (new_v1.at(i) % 2 != 0)` then it works correctly.
Why does that happen and is there a problem with the equal operator?
If yes then why are the evens getting printed even if they are negatives while still using the equal operator?

Code here for reference.

```
clude <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void fillVector(vector <int>&);

void printVector(const vector <int>&);

void printEvensAndOddsVector(const vector <int>&); // Prints Evens and Odds.

int main()
{
    vector <int> v1;

    fillVector(v1);
    printVector(v1);
    printEvensAndOddsVector(v1);

    cout << "\n\n\n";
    system( "pause");
    return 0;
}

// Function Definitions
void fillVector(vector <int>& new_v1)
{
    int number;
    cout << "Type in numbers and type -100 to stop: ";
    cin >> number;

    while (number != -100)
    {
        new_v1.push_back(number);
        cin >> number;
    }
}

void printVector(const vector <int>& new_v1)
{
    cout << "\nVector: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < new_v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << new_v1.at(i) << " ";
    }
    cout << " \n";
}

void printEvensAndOddsVector(const vector <int>& new_v1)
{
    cout << "Vector Evens: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < new_v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (new_v1.at(i) % 2 == 0)
        {
            cout << new_v1.at(i) << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << " \n";

    cout << "Vector Odds: ";
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < new_v1.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (new_v1.at(i) % 2 == 1)
        {
            cout << new_v1.at(i) << " ";
        }
    }
    cout << " \n";
}
```

Comment: Do you need all of this code to demonstrate a simple issue with the modulo operator?  A 3 or 4 line `main()` program is all you need.

Comment: The result of `%` on a negative number is probably negative.

Comment: @Paul yea i know that but the question still remains.I am not asking how is the fastest or best way to code it. I am doing this program for a reason and my code dosn't work. my question is why is that?

Comment: My point is that you have an issue with the '%' operator.  Therefore a simple main() program showing usage of the '%' operator is all that was needed.  Not vectors, not functions, etc...

Comment: @Roger nope i checked it too. https://encrypted.google.com/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=-5+mod+2&btnG=&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1

Comment: @Johnson How does a Google calculator tell you anything about the behaviour of `%` in C++?

Comment: @Johnson: That calculator link says nothing about how things work in C++.

Comment: @Johnson You're seriously not listening here. We're trying to help.

Comment: @Johnson Please look here: http://ideone.com/peAtQi  See how simple it is to write a program, and then present your question using a simple example?  Not only will it help us, it helps you, and it may also help someone searching on SO for similar issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modulo operator with negative values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values)

Comment: Roger sorry  i didnt say you are not tring to help i am just stating that the google calculator gives the result of a mathematical expresion right? Shouldnt that be universal? If a calculator says the remainder of something == 1 shouldnt that be the correct thing?

Comment: You're confusing mathematics with C++ standards. They are not the same thing. Read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7594577/2065121) that @NPE linked to.

Comment: You can use '&1' instead of '%2'.The problem already explained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This line: `if (new_v1.at(i) % 2 == 1)`. It prints the numbers that are odd but only the positive ones not the negative ones.

For negative `n`, `n % 2` returns either `0` or `-1` in C++. It never returns `1`, so the condition cannot be true for negative inputs.

As you've discovered, comparing to zero would work.

See [Modulo operator with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values)

Comment: Oh that explain why even  work still cause its 0 right?

Also then why is: https://encrypted.google.com/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=-5+mod+2&btnG=&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1 saying remainder 1 and not -1 ?

Comment: Ok mate thanks now i understand and chose best answer in 7 minutes.