# Modulo Operator (%) gives divergent results

Tags: c++, c++11

Given this Example:

```
std::vector<int> numbers = {5,6,7}; //size is 3
int i = -1; 
std::cout << i % 3 <<"\n";                  // output: -1
std::cout << i % numbers.size() << "\n";    // output: 0
```

basically in both statements im processing -1 % 3 but the compiler outputs different numbers. I don't understand this outcome, maybe someone can explain it to me.

**edit:** as @Chris,@Keith Thompson @AnT suggested the snippet

```
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() % 3 <<"\n";     //output: 0
std::cout << i % numbers.size() << "\n";                            // output: 0
```

prints the expected output. Thanks for the helpful advice to everyone!

Comment: See Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values

Comment: @RollenD'Souza: That's actually unrelated.

Comment: The problem is that "numbers.size()" happens to be "unsigned int"; and the "-1" is converted to "0xffffffff" (or whatever the value for your architecture) behind your back :(

Comment: @FoggyDay: No, the `-1` isn't converted to `1`. It's converted to `SIZE_MAX`.

Comment: @Grundkurs: `i % numbers.size()` is not `-1 % 3`. It is actually `(std::vector<int>::size_type) i % numbers.size()`. And `(std::vector<int>::size_type) i` is no longer `-1`. It is some large unsigned value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`i % 3` is what you expect and, since C++11, has defined semantics rather than having an implementation-defined (if I recall correctly) result.

`numbers.size()` has an unsigned type (`std::size_t`). Assuming `size_t` is as big as `int` or bigger, `i` is converted to the same unsigned type before the operation is performed. The value `i` gets will be the maximum value for that type, which looks to be divisible by 3 for you.

Comment: As a side-note, cranking up the warning-level on the compiler should have caught the sign-mismatch.

Comment: @Deduplicator, Interesting, I didn't know that. Apparently [Clang doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e425e23f148a1f03), [nor GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7353cc43b82d22c3), or at least these versions.

Comment: Try `-Weverything`, and see which warning they threw out of `-Wextra`.

Comment: @Deduplicator, Ah, I see. Now I'm thinking of whether it's worth adding that specific warning (`‑Wsign‑conversion`) to my options. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is % of negative numbers is not well-defined in C++.

Comment: Except from C++11 onwards.