# C - rand() modulo 0

Tags: c, random, int, modulo

When I am trying to generate a random number 0 through `int`:

```
//Populate Currently Allocated Reasource for each customer
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS; i++) 
{
    printf("%d:[ ",i);
    for (j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_RESOURCES; j++)
    {
        allocation[i][j] = rand() % maximum[i][j];
        printf("%d ",allocation[i][j]);
    }
    printf("] \n\n");
}
```

I get a floating point exception when `maximum[i][j]` is 0.

Are there any better means of creating a random number without the `floating point error` caused by `rand() % 0`?

EDIT:
When maximum is 0, the random number output should just be 0.

Comment: Ask you rmath-teacher why division by 0 is undefined.

Comment: Are `allocation[][]` and `maximum[][]` arrays of `int`s, or `float`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> When maximum is 0, the random number output should just be 0.

You can add a check to take care of this.

```
if ( maximum[i][j] == 0 )
{
   allocation[i][j] = 0;
}
else
{
   allocation[i][j] = rand() % maximum[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking `a % b` gives you the remainder when `a` is divided by `b`. As such, it will always give you a result that is less than `b`, and it doesn't work when `b` is zero, because you can't divide by zero.

If you want a random number between 0 and `x`, you need to take `rand() % (x + 1)`.

Comment: What if maximum is negative?

Comment: @naltipar Then things get weird. The behavior of the modulo operator with negative numbers is implementation-defined. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this instead

```
//Populate Currently Allocated Reasource for each customer
for (i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CUSTOMERS; i++) 
{
    printf("%d:[ ",i);
    for (j = 0; j < NUMBER_OF_RESOURCES; j++)
    {
        allocation[i][j] = maximum[i][j] ? (rand() % maximum[i][j]) : 0;
        printf("%d ",allocation[i][j]);
    }
    printf("] \n\n");
}
```

Comment: What is this format called?  And where may I find documentation on its useages?

Comment: I means, if the `maximum[i][j]` not 0 than assign `(rand() % maximum[i][j])` to `allocation[i][j]` else assign 0 to `allocation[i][j]`

Comment: @Sean, look for ternary operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `?:` operator to write that extra condition neatly:

```
allocation[i][j] = maximum[i][j] ? (rand() % maximum[i][j]) : 0;
```

> ?:    **Conditional Expression**: *If Condition is true ? Then value X : Otherwise value Y*

---

> In computer programming, ?: is a ternary operator that is part of the syntax for a basic conditional expression in several programming languages. It is commonly referred to as the conditional operator, inline if (iif), or ternary if.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Answer (score 0):

> When maximum is 0, the random number output should just be 0.

The modulo operator is the remainder after a division. Since division by zero is undefined, so is modulo 0.

You need a condition to prevent attempting to divide by zero. You can do that with `if`/`else` statements, or the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) (`?:`). In other words, change this

```
allocation[i][j] = rand() % maximum[i][j];
```

to one of the following.

```
if (maximum[i][j] == 0)
{
    allocation[i][j] = 0;
}
else
{
    allocation[i][j] = (rand() % maximum[i][j]);
}
```

or

```
allocation[i][j] = (maximum[i][j] == 0) ? (rand() % maximum[i][j]) : 0;
```

Comment: Of course, for better or worse, the condition `(maximum[i][j] == 0)` can be further abbreviated due to `maximum[i][j]`, since 0 evaluates as false in C. But I think the explicit condition is more clear.