# Why mod operation return 0 when one is size_t type and the other is <0?

Tags: c++

there is c++ code:

```
string s = "abc";
size_t len = s.length();
cout<<(-1%len)<<endl;//print 0
```

but if change size_t to int:

```
string s = "abc";
int len = s.length();
cout<<(-1%len)<<endl;//print -1
```

why this happens,anyone can explain this,thanks!

Comment: `"abc".length();` should not compile. Can you show your actual example?

Comment: @BillyONeal,please add include <string.h>,I'm using c++ string.

Comment: `"abc"` is not a C++ string under any circumstances. Please post examples that will compile.

Comment: @BillyONeal,sorry,updated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modulo operator with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottom line is your first code snippet boils down to `-1 % size_t{3}` and starts by converted `-1` to type `size_t`, resulting in FFFF FFFF if a 32-bit program, or FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF if 64-bit.  Either's a multiple of 3 so the mod operator returns `0`.  In the other case with two (signed) `int` values `-1 % 3` return `-1`, as you'd hopefully expect.