# Caesar Encryption and decryption C++

Tags: c++, encryption, caesar-cipher

I would like to know how to limit the ASCII range of encryption from 32 - 126.

For our task we are supposed to convert string to char and encrypt/decrypt each individual char.

I'm currently using this for encryption

```
int value = (value-32+shift)%95+32 //value is the current ascii value of a                 
                                   //character
                                   //the first shift is given by the user with regards 
                                   //to how many shifts he wants to do to the right
```

and this for decryption

```
int value = (value-32-shift)%95+32
```

my encryption is working perfectly (when I quote out the decryption function) but my decryption is not working how it is supposed to.

extra note: We only have to do a right shift when encoding, a single string is given for our entire program to encrypt and decrypt ("This is C++")

```
Give shift: 3
Wklv#lv#F..
DECODE 
Wklv#lv#F..  //must be 'THIS is C++'
ENCODE       //shift=15
This is C++  //must be 'cwx#/x#/R::'  
DECODE 
EYZdpZdp4{{  //must be 'THIS is C++'
ENCODE      //shift=66
cwx#/x#/R::  //must be "8LMWbMWb'mm"
DECODE 
This is C++
ENCODE       //shift=94
cwx#/x#/R::  //must be 'SGHR~hr~B**'
DECODE 
This is C++
```

Note: in process of adding more code description

Comment: We need a [mcve].  Please note the "Minimal" there.  We only want to see *one* fixed shift, the output you expect, and the output you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is explained in [Modulo operator with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7594508/771073).  I'm not sure this is an exact duplicate.  The problem is that decoding a cipher character like '!' with a shift of more than one (say "3")

```
int value = (value-32-shift)%95+32
          = ('!'-32-3)%95+32
          = (33-32-3)%95+32
          = (-2)%95 + 32
          = -2 + 32
          = 30
```

Oops.  You need to use:

```
int value = (value-32+(95-shift))%95+32
```

Answer (score 2):

The probelm is that `(value-32-shift)` can become negative. The modulo operation does not 'wrap around', but actually 'mirrors' around zero (see [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values) if you want to know why).
To ensure that your value stays positive, add 95 before doing the modulo operation:

```
int value = (value-32-shift+95)%95+32
```