# range of modulus operator in verilog

Tags: random, operators, verilog

What is range of % operator in Verilog? In C I know if I write number%10 then output is between 0 and 9. But I tried in Verilog and result I am getting is between -9 and 9? Why is that?

```
enter code here
module testbench;
integer i;
reg signed [15:0] a,b;
initial
begin
for(i = 0; i < 9; i = i + 1)
begin
    a= $random%10;
    b= $random%20;  
    $display("A: %d and B : %d",a,b);
end
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modulus can return negative numbers as clearly stated in Verilog's IEEE Std 1364-2001 § 4.1.5 *Arithmetic operators* as well as SystemVerilog's [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 11.4.3 *Arithmetic operators*

> The result of a modulus operation shall take the sign of the first operand.

Both LRMs (Language Reference Manual) also give examples.

To guarantee a positive number, you can use `$unsigned()`. Example:

```
a = $unsigned($random) % 10;
```

If you enable SystemVerilog, you can replace `$unsigned($random)` with `$urandom` or replace `$unsigned($random) % 10` with `$urandom_range(9, 0)`; see [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) § 18.13 *Random number system functions and methods*

---

FYI : C/C++ does the same with negative numbers. Refer to prior answered questions: [Modulo operation with negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers) and [Modulo operator with negative values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values)