# Decrypting Caesar cipher fails when offset is 11 or more

Tags: c++

I am doing a decryption program. I've been looking and trying to figure this out, but I don't see anything. So when I decrypt such as `9adwrqxvni0348&4#9` it comes out fine, but when I have an offset of `11` or more it decrypts all but the last character. No matter what the offset past `11` is the last character is that same. I just now stuck all letters in, and they work. It is just the last number character that does not work past `11`.

```
for (int count = 0; count < length; count++)
{
    if (msg[count] >= 'a' && msg[count] <= 'z')//Letter wraping
    {
        dmsg += ((msg[count] - 'a' - offset + 26) % 26) + 'a';
    }
    else if (msg[count] >= '0' && msg[count] <= '9')//Number wraping
    {
        dmsg += (abs(msg[count] - '0' - offset + 10) % 10) + '0';
    }       
}
```

Comment: did you try count <= length?

Comment: Might be your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values

Comment: If code is 10bexrrywoi1459&4#9 then it comes in as                                run home 1459. which is right.    If the offset is 11 or more then it comes out                                                                                                                   run home 1451. No matter what the offset is above 11. Weird

Comment: @JakePurdom Have you tried stepping through the program with a debugger?

Comment: Why does `1459` decode to `1459`? Shouldn't it decode to something else that depends on the offset?

Comment: To know the correct way to decode it, we need to see how the encoding algorithm works.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me that when the offset becomes greater than 10, adding 10 doesn't create the appropriate positive value on any digit that is equal to or less than the difference between the offset and 10.  One work around is to mod 10 the offset:

```
dmsg += ( abs( msg[count] - '0' - ( offset % 10 ) + 10 ) % 10 ) + '0';
```

Comment: @JakePurdom -  You're very welcome.  One thing to keep in mind.  The same thing will probably occur with letters, if the offset is greater than 26.

Comment: @JakePurdom - If you've found an answer that answers your question, please remember to mark it so.  Thanks.