# GCD if positive and negative numbers

Tags: c++, math, language-agnostic, greatest-common-divisor

As mentioned [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/GCD_for_Negative_Integers): `gcd(a,b) = gcd(-a,b) = gcd(-a,-b)`. However when I use following code, I get different output for input being (-4,-8).

`gcd(x,y)` gives -4 wheras `gcd(abs(x),abs(y))` gives 4.

Can some one help me understand where I am wrong.

```
int gcd(int a ,int b)
{
    if(b==0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b,a%b);
}
 int main()
{
    int x,y;
    cin>>x>>y;
    cout<<gcd(x,y)<<endl;   // gives -4
    cout<<gcd(abs(x),abs(y))<<endl;   //gives 4
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values

Comment: It's not a dupe imo, but surely they are related

Comment: Your basis case is wrong (in the presence of negative values). Why not return `abs(a)`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not taking into account that the output range has a plus or minus sign in it which breaks your algorithm, it's asserting that negative numbers and positive numbers are to be treated as the positive integers.  Formal set theory in discrete mathematics has a different jargon set for symbols that are incompatible with most programming languages.

**Greatest Common Denominator in C++ using recursion**

```
int GCD(int A,int B)
{
    if(A==0) return B;
    if(B==0) return A;
    A=abs(A);
    B=abs(B);
    if(A>B) return GCD(B,A);
    return GCD(B%A,A);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm cannot cover all positive and negative numbers. Use the code below.

```
int gcd(int a, int b){
    a = abs(a);b = abs(b);
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    if (a == b)
        return a;
    if (a > b)
        return gcd(a - b, b);
    return gcd(a, b - a);
}
```