# C++ calling single helper function with *this attributes

Tags: c++, performance, operator-overloading, this, fractions

Edit: I’m a beginner to C++, and I’d like to understand more about how to optimize my code.

I have created a Fraction object in C++ as well as overloaded +, - operations etc. When I came to the unary operators, however, I realized I didn't know how to reduce the fraction in the most efficient manner. So I have a function gcd that finds the greatest divisor:

```
int gcd (int n, int m) {

int newN = n < 0 ? -n : n;
int newM = m < 0 ? -m : m;
if (newM <= newN && newN % newM == 0) { return newM; }
else if (newN < newM) { return gcd(newM, newN); }
else { return gcd(newM, newN%newM); }
}
```

and then I have an overloaded operator, for example, incrementation:

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator++() {
num = num + denom;

//reduce fraction
int divisor = gcd(denom,num);
num = num/divisor;
denom = denom/divisor;
if (num < 0 && denom < 0) {num *= (-1);}
if (denom < 0) {denom *= (-1);}

return *this;
}
```

For efficiency, I would like to put the `reduce fraction` part of the code in a separate **single** helper function so the final function would look like this:

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator++() {
num = num + denom;

//reduce fraction
reduce(num, denom);

return *this;
}
```

That way I don't have to copy and paste whatever is in `//reduce fraction` everytime I overload a unary operator for example. However, I'm not sure how the reduce(Fraction num, Fraction& denom) function should look like. At most I can implement it like this:

```
void reduce(int& num, int& denom) {
int divisor = gcd(denom,num);
num = num/divisor;
denom = denom/divisor;
if (num < 0 && denom < 0) {num *= (-1);}
if (denom < 0) {denom *= (-1);}
}
```

I'm sure the code above will run into issues during compilation, so I was wondering if I could be suggested any pointers as to efficiently create the reduce fraction function. This is maybe being a bit nitpicky since my original code runs fine, but since I am new to C++, I'd like to learn more about how I can make my code more efficient. Thanks a lot! Let me know if more information is needed.

Edit: The above code does not work. Compiles correctly, but does not reduce fraction properly. So 1/2 + 1/4 results in 6/8, not 3/4.

Comment: It seems you want `void reduce(int& num, int& denom)`.

Comment: Whoops thanks, I've fixed that in my code.

Comment: references are still missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well on a high level your gcd function is too complicated and the last part of reduce is a bit wrong. If only denom is negative you invert it.
Nicely shows why it's always a good idea to put code into proper functions because they can also be separately tested. So I'd suggest writing some unit tests for your reduce and gcd functions.
Start with a simple solution like

```
static int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

and adapt if needed for negative numbers considering [% semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594508/modulo-operator-with-negative-values). Thinking about it the function should already be fine like that and you just need to call std::abs(gcd(n,d)) in reduce.

In general you should ask yourself if you really want to pay the renormalization cost at every single operation or if you let the user decide when to call reduce.

For lower-level optimizations here are some hints:

- Always test/measure, e.g. by looking at what the compiler actually produces with [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/D-5K9U).
- The recursion in gcd is not a problem from a performance point of view in this case as it's [tail recursive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) and the compiler will turn it into a loop for you.
- The out parameters in reduce are bad for optimizations cause the compiler has to prove they don't point to the same object. Returning a std::pair and using C++11 std::tie or C++17 structured bindings at the callsite if possible is way more elegant.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth answer, but I say I’m afraid my current understanding of C++ does not allow me to fully comprehend the details of what you’re explaining here (except for the simplification of gcd here) nor the site explanation given. In short, can you give an explanation of what tips you would give a beginner of how to implement what you’ve written here, or based on the code given in the question details? Many thanks.

Comment: In addition to your question as to why the negation happens, I’m not sure if I’ve pegged this down — but the first negation handles only numerator negation and second negation handles denominator. Because I can’t instantiate a fraction like (-7/-2) or (7/-2), it is necessary (afaic) to check both the numerator and denominator.

Comment: I've restructured and augmented the answer, moving advanced topics to the end. Regarding the negation in reduce just check what happens if only denom is negative but not num. Then go through the other cases in your mind.

Comment: A unit test just transforms this mental process into code. You call e.g. reduce with different values for num and denom (negative and positive) so you cover all cases and check the results. Then you can also step through with your debugger and see what happens in realtime. There are really nice test frameworks like https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#writing-tests but as a quick and dirty way to get started you can also just test it in your main by printing the results.

Comment: Example using standard assert, you can ignore the right half: https://godbolt.org/z/_24j69